# Creating Google-Charts in PDF using VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce

i cant view the charts when i render the visual-force page as PDFs

Comment: where is the issue then?

Answer (score 2):

Google charts are created using the javascript , and javascript dont gets executed when the page is rendered as pdf.
So you will not be able to show the google chart on your pdf page.

Comment: What you can do is save your google chart as an attachment and then use that   attachment to be rendered in pdf.